# AI generator to restyle a user's photo

Tags: neural-networks, image-generation

I'd like to know what AI-driven image generator (neural network) can be used to take any user selfie and stylize it into, say, a New York Yankees fan. Or as if the user were wearing Gucci clothes.

In my initial research, I was able to determine that this is called an "image-to-image" transformation with a text prompt.

I assume that Midjourney or DALL-E can be used, but I'm not sure which generator is better suited for this scenario.

And which prompt should be used to achieve the desired transformation.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AI Stack Exchange. We're more about the theory than the products at the moment, although I could see that changing given the popularity of the media and text generators. Could you please give an indication of how technical you are as a software user? My gut feeling is that Stable Diffusion with in-painting and control net extension would be the way to go, but the setup and use of this is quite involved if you are not used to installing and running open-source projects

Comment: Also, worth giving an indication, maybe by way of example, of what kinds of "side-effect" changes you are expecting or willing to accept. For example, using a selfie as an image prompt in Midjourney will capture broad parts of the description, e.g. hair colour and style, but will typically change the person to only be partially recognisable, more like a sibling or cousin of the original person in the photo. And it will often change the pose and other details

Comment: @NeilSlater Hi Neil, thanks for your reply. I'm quite familiar with conventional software, but AI and neural networks are rather new to me. So I'm looking for a relatively simple solution. For example, I already tried Runaway image-to-image, but the problem was exactly as you described: After processing, the person on the selfie was a different person. She had a different face. I wonder if there is a simple solution where only the clothing is replaced with a text prompt, but the person remains largely unchanged. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to Photoshop? The beta version includes generated fill that may be exactly what you want. It's not clear though whether you are wanting to automate 100s of pictures (to some acceptable level), as opposed to making a few bespoke images to best quality that you can manage. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qM2U4VHOrY

Answer (score 1):

Those types of models exist, and they are called image-to-image generators like you pointed out. You are talking about a feature called "style transfer", which is one of the biggest use-cases for such models. [The huggingface website gives a neat explanation of the details](https://huggingface.co/tasks/image-to-image).

> Image-to-image is the task of transforming a source image to match the characteristics of a target image or a target image domain. Any image manipulation and enhancement is possible with image to image models.

In order to use one yourself, you could train your own model (very hard), use a pretrained model (hard) or use an existing solution like [Runaway's Image-to-Image generator](https://runwayml.com/ai-magic-tools/image-to-image/). There are multiple easy-to-use alternatives as well.

[Also check out this project](https://phillipi.github.io/pix2pix/) if you are interested in the training process of image-to-image models.